# How can I resolve a conflict between Homebrew and MacPorts or Fink?

Tags: npm, homebrew, macports, fink

I was running through an npm tutorial and I needed to install Homebrew. However, after getting one error (cannot install node using available compilers), I ran brew install gcc. Well, that took forever, but it ultimately didn't work because apparently I have either MacPorts or Fink installed.

To be honest, I am not sure when I installed either MacPorts or Fink. I don't remember hearing them before or using them, and I'm not sure what they're used for. Has anyone run into this error before, or have any advice on what to do next? Below are the errors and the links I got in terminal. Thanks!

```
make[2]: *** [configure-stage2-target-libstdc++-v3] Error 1
make[1]: *** [stage2-bubble] Error 2
make: *** [bootstrap] Error 2
Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
Software installed with other package managers causes known problems for
Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try again.

READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting

These open issues may also help:
`gcc`: Force DWARF-2 Debugging Data under Pre-Mavericks https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/46111
freeimage: patches for gcc 5.0 https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/44612
yap: don't use GCC 5, which breaks https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/45977
gcc can't find compatible ISL https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/44444
How Do I Specify and Use Homebrew gcc-4.8 in a Formula Instead of OS X Bundled gcc? https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/46169
isl 0.15, cloog 0.18.4, gcc compatibility patch https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/44486
gcc causes false alarms in C++ stdlib check https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/45218
apple-gcc42 takes priority over modern gcc https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/41055
gcc 4.9.2 fails to produce debugging information https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/34976
Object files deleted during build of gcc needed by gdb https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/35734
MacOS.(gcc|clang|llvm)_version can return nil https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/18781
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacPorts and Fink are package managers for OS X, like Homebrew. As the message says Homebrew doesn’t work well with these two, so you should either stay with MacPorts or Fink, or uninstall them and use Homebrew.

Outside of that, you can check [Homebrew’s troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Troubleshooting.md#check-for-common-issues) to learn how to fix common issues.

Comment: Is it an issue if I cannot find an instance of either Fink or MacPorts installed on my computer? I mean, /Applications/MacPorts doesn't exist because MacPorts is not in my Applications directory (from what I can see).

Comment: Do `/sw/bin/fink` or `/opt/local/bin/port` exist?

Comment: When I use Spotlight to find either Fink or MacPorts, I get no results. Where else would I find these locations? Also I tried running `fink --list` to get a list of known fink installation packages, but I get `bash: fink: command not found`. I tried running `sudo port -fp uninstall installed` but I get `no ports matched the given expression`. I guess that could mean no **ports** are functioning?

Comment: OK, I tried running `which port` and I got `/opt/local/bin/port` as the response. I get nothing when trying to run `which fink`.

Comment: Adding for posterity.... Ran the rest of the uninstall and Homebrew seems to be working. Thanks!

Comment: It would have been sufficient to purge `/opt/local`-related paths from the search path of your shell, linker and preprocessor (Variables `PATH`, `(DY)LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `INCLUDEPATH`) for the duration of the build and install. That way you could have kept your MacPorts installation. In the likely case that HomeBrew serves all your needs though, it's certainly less potential for confusion to stick with that port system/package manager.